# How can I save the output from Python loop to CSV file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I would like to save the output from the following Python loop to CSV

```
ticker_list = ['GBX', 'AYI', 'SMPL', 'BSET']

from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials as yf

yahoo_financials = yf(ticker_list)

price = yahoo_financials.get_historical_price_data('2019-07-02', '2019-07-02', 'daily')

df = pd.DataFrame(price)


def get_price():
    df1 = pd.DataFrame()
    for i in ticker_list:
        df1_i = pd.DataFrame(df[i]['prices'])
        df1_i['ticker'] = i
        df1 = df1.append(df1_i)

    df1.to_csv(r'price_20190702.csv')
```

I want to save the price info for all four tickers to a single CSV file.  However, when I call `def get_price()`, no CSV file is saved.

Comment: Did you mean `df1.to_csv(r'price_20190702.csv')`?

Comment: Can you show sample output data?

Comment: Yes, I meant df1.to_csv(r'price_20190702.csv')

Comment: Can you be kindly more specific about using an array?  Thanks.

Comment: adjclose close date formatted_date high low open volume ticker
0 30.141232 30.400000 1561728600 2019-06-28 30.600000 29.370001 29.379999 874200 GBX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd
from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials as yf

TICKER_LIST = ['GBX', 'AYI', 'SMPL', 'BSET']
yahoo_financials = yf(TICKER_LIST)
price = yahoo_financials.get_historical_price_data('2019-07-02', '2019-07-02', 'daily')

df = pd.DataFrame()
for t in TICKER_LIST:
    df = df.append(price[t], ignore_index=True)
df.to_csv('price_20190702.csv', index=False)
```

Output:

```
eventsData,firstTradeDate,id,isPending,prices,timeZone
{},"{'formatted_date': '1994-07-14', 'date': 774172800}",1d15620256001562025600,0.0,[],{'gmtOffset': -14400}
{},"{'formatted_date': '2001-12-03', 'date': 1007370000}",1d15620256001562025600,0.0,[],{'gmtOffset': -14400}
{},"{'formatted_date': '2017-07-05', 'date': 1499241600}",1d15620256001562025600,0.0,[],{'gmtOffset': -14400}
{},"{'formatted_date': '1980-03-17', 'date': 322131600}",1d15620256001562025600,0.0,[],{'gmtOffset': -14400}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use with open

For Example:

```
while True:
   data = 'Changes every time'
   with open('t.csv','a') as f:
      wr = csv.writer(f)
      wr.writerow(data)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion!